# Changing a html variable in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following variable in React

```
  let Example = (
    <div>
      Hello World
    </div>
  );
```

I would like to change its content (text, tags, etc.)

Is that possiable to do?
What is the type of this variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just overwrite your variable in another statement and this is a jsx Element.

https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Comment: I don't want to overwrite it, just to remove a html tag for example

Comment: The best option would then be to create a react component. 
Here the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for react components and props?
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props

The type of your variable would be a JavaScript function and you can use react props to modify your content.

Answer (score 0):

Use functions!

```
const myContent = () => {
    // Some js
    return 'Hello!';
  }

  const Example = () => (
    <div>
      {myContent()}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the content of a JSX snippet that's a crystal clear hint that what you need is a component.

In your example, you can try something like this.

```
const SayHello = ({ name }) => <div>Hello {name}</div>
```

Then you can use it as a regular component.

```
<SayHello name="world" />
```

You can bound the value to a variable, and then the component will be updated with any update of that variable.

```
let name = this.aMethodToGetAValue();
return <SayHello name={name} />
```